# update from php 5.4.x to 5.5.38 still can't use doctrine/common

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, php-5.5, php-5.4

My system is using ubuntu 12.10 and apache 2.2.22 and using doctrince 2.4.
I updated my Php from 5.4.x to 5.5.38.
But i still countered this error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /var/www/xxxxxx/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php on line 62`

At first, i thought it was my php 5.4 caused and then i updated php to 5.5.38. 
Yet i still get this error.
I really have no idea how to fix it.
I can't update Ubuntu's packages from outside of the server.
Please someone help me.

Comment: Line 62 of this class contains Proxy::class (class name resolution). This feature definetly supported by PHP 5.5. So, are you sure that code works on 5.5? (try to add phpversion() call directly before this line).

Comment: on my  desktop i am using php 5.5.x and working smoothly.  And hwne i get my chance to lay my finger on the server then i knew it's using php 5.4. on searching on google, someone claim that  doctrince/common need at least php5.5. That's why i updatae my php

Comment: MyPhp can't parse here: `protected $placeholders = [
        'baseProxyInterface'   => Proxy::class,
        'additionalProperties' => '',
    ];`

Comment: i tried add `phpversion()` and get `unexpected 'phpversion' (T_STRING)`

Comment: i'm not sure i understand you correctly: i meant to add something like that: `var_dump(phpversion());` at line before 62 (or in any other place that parsed/executed early).

Comment: OMG! you are right.  i tried it and got '`5.4.6-1ubuntu1.8`. I can't believe. I did update and  use `php --version ' or something like that.  Why did the parser still  use php 5.4 ???  I dowloaded from php.net then installed manually.

Comment: i really don't know how to fix it now T_T. i wish i could just  reinstall new version of ubuntu  but can't.

Comment: I don't know how PHP was installed/updated. There are various ways to do that (building from sources, using some PPA, distro updating, etc), but it depends on your environment and requirements. Anyway, it's not a PHP issue.

Comment: are you sure you restarted your apache after installing php5? this is a mandatory step when upgrading php.

Comment: I restarted  but is still using php 5.4.x